# Document AI adding folders

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai, cloud-document-ai

I'm using Document AI to parse PDF files from one bucket and then save them as JSON in another bucket in GCS. However, Document AI creates a folder with a subfolder in my bucket.

I've read a lot and I can see that this is normal behavior for Document AI. Is there any way to save the JSON files directly to the bucket without any additional folders?

All the help will be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior for Document AI Batch Processing and there is not a way to directly output the JSON files directly into the bucket.

You could use `gsutil` to "flatten" out the JSON files into the top folder, something like this.

```bash
gsutil mv gs://bucket-name/*/*/*.json gs://bucket-name/
```